# Python/GCP sanity check: is this correct means of referencing image stored in GCP Storage in a POST call

Tags: python, post, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

**Scenario:** an image file stored in a GCP bucket need to be sent to a third-party REST endpoint via a POST

**Question:** Is this really the best pattern? Is there a more efficient less verbose way?

We have images being uploaded by a mobile app to a GCP Storage bucket. When the finalize event for the image upload fires we have a GCP Cloud Function (Python 3) that reacts to this by getting ref to uploaded image, downloads it to a temp file, and then uses that temp file as the image source for the POST. This is our current code and it works, but to my eye seems convoluted with the multiple `open` commands. More specifically: is there a better way to simply get the image blob from GCP Storage and simply attach it to the POST call without first saving it as a local file and then opening it so it can be attached to the POST?

```
def third_party_upload(data, context):
  # get image from bucket
  storage_client = storage.Client()
  bucket = storage_client.bucket(data['bucket'])
  image_blob = bucket.get_blob(data['name'])
  download_path = '/tmp/{}.jpg'.format(str(uuid.uuid4())) #temp image file download location

  # save GCP Storage blob as a temp file
  with open(download_path, 'wb') as file_obj:
    image_blob.download_to_file(file_obj)

    # open temp file and send to 3rd-party via rest post call
    with open(download_path, 'rb') as img:
      files = {'image': (data['name'], img, 'multipart/form-data', {'Expires': '0'}) }

      headers = {
            'X-Auth-Token': api_key,
            'Content-Type': 'image/jpg',
            'Accept': 'application/json'
      }

      # make POST call
      response = requests.post(third_party_endpoint, headers=headers, files=files)
      print('POST response:', response)
```

*Update: a couple of commenters have mentioned that Signed URLs are a possibility and I agree they are an excellent choice. However we are stuck with a requirement to include the image binary as the POST body. Signed-URLs won't work in this case.*

Comment: Why not send a link to the object in Cloud Storage instead of POSTing the object as data?

Comment: Permissions - we'd need to provide the 3rd party access to our bucket or make the bucket public - both of which are no-go's

Comment: Use Signed URLs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTTP method POST requires data. You must provide that data in the HTTP request. There is no magic method to obtain Cloud Storage data except to read it. The process is to read the data from Cloud Storage and then provide that data to the POST request.

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to send a URL to the third-party endpoint instead of the actual image contents, you could use Signed URLs give time-limited access to the image without needing to provide the 3rd party access to the bucket or make the bucket public.

More information here: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls

Comment: Very good idea however the 3rd-party has confirmed the POST body must contain the image binary. Clunky but we're stuck with it.

Comment: @JohnHanley Not really - within the restriction of needing to embed the image: "More specifically: is there a better way to simply get the image blob from GCP Storage and simply attach it to the POST call without first saving it as a local file and then opening it so it can be attached to the POST?"

Comment: @Gatmando - The HTTP method POST requires data. You must provide that data in the HTTP request. There is no magic method to obtain Cloud Storage data except to read it. The process is read the data from Cloud Storage and then provide that data to the POST request.

Comment: @JohnHanley enter this as an answer and you'll get the credit